# axios could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am making a mobile app with react native, whenever I try to import Axios I cannnot import it. I have installed Axios and everything is fine. But I get this error

```
Android Bundling failed 1097ms
Unable to resolve module axios from F:\HS International\araf\features\ChatWindow.js: axios could not be found within the project or in these directories:      
  node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  1 | import { React, useState } from 'react';
  2 | import { Alert, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button, TouchableHighlight, Image } from 'react-native'; 
> 3 | import axios from 'axios';
    |                    ^
  4 |
  5 | function ChatWindow(props) {
  6 |     const [userMessage, setUserMessage] = useState("");
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried importing like you do but i guess it have some problems you can try  require it like that

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
```